# Ubuntu 13.10 freezes at times; *ERROR* stuck on render ring

Tags: 13.10, freeze, ram

My ubuntu 13.10 laptop freezes relatively frequently, after I recently installed it.  It is most common while I am playing Minecraft, but I have also had it happen at other times.  I think it may be a memory leak, but I thought the computer should not freeze when the ram is used.
From time to time, I will also get messages in the TTY about an error.  One I just got 
`[4407.784295] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* stuck on render ring.`  I believe there was another line below it, but I was running htop at the time and the line cuts off after `[4407`

I am on an Asus computer with 4 GB of RAM and 4 GB swap space.  I am not new to Linux nor the command line, but this is completely new to me. I will offer any additional information that you need.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have finally solved this problem. Someone online suggested that I switch to SNA instead of UXA, which is a setting for the graphics drivers. I followed [these instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-enable-intel-sna-acceleration-in.html):

Create an `xorg.conf` file:

```
gksu gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and add the following text:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
EndSection
```

Save and exit, and reboot.

I also had to install the xorg-edgers drivers, which is also explained in the article. The [PPA's Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) explains the usage of the PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

To remove this ppa if necessary, be sure to use `ppa-purge` to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me pretty often on Minecraft and Hl2DM. I solved it by limiting the FPS to about 30. SNA UXA switching didn't work for me. I'm running Lubuntu 13.10 on Dell Vostro 3450.